# blocked by CORS policy but still POST request is performed, HOW?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, http-post

**I had a server running on localhost port 3000 using NodeJs.** 

There I had a database linked and had 2 basic POST methods (Create and Delete)*.

*(I had not written any extra checking for request headers)

I was curious to know  **if only client-side JS (with a dummy HTML page) can perform the deletion by itself!**

I wrote [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYBpQ.png) in the client-side js (in a separate directory )

After trying the POST Delete operation like this , 
I got this [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AHTO.png)

But  **even though error was raised, the "Deletion Operation" was still performed succesfully**  and the data with the specific id was deleted!

My Question is **"what exactly is blocked if it was not the deletion operation ?**

Comment: Does it happen consistently when you try again?

Comment: yes, I have tried 2-3 times each time database was accessed and data was deleted successfully!

Answer (score 1):

With CORS, requests are never blocked on server-side. It will only instruct the browser to not send the requests if possible (with PRE-FLIGHT).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: then is there any way to prevent the operation on the server-side?